# Recursive "decorator" in Kotlin

Tags: python, kotlin, python-decorators, memoization

Suppose I have a recursive function like `fibonacci`:

```
fun fibonacci(n: Int): BigInteger = 
    if (n < 2) 
        n.toBigInteger() 
    else 
        fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

This is slow because I'm recalculating known values a bunch of times. I can fix this by adding a "memo":

```
val memo = ConcurrentSkipListMap<Int, BigInteger>()

fun mFibonacci(n: Int): BigInteger = 
    memo.computeIfAbsent(n) { 
        if (n < 2) 
            it.toBigInteger() 
        else 
            mFibonacci(n-1) + mFibonacci(n-2) 
    }
```

Works like a charm, but can I do this without touching the function? My first thought was to use a wrapper class:

```
class Cached<in T, out R>(private val f: (T) -> R) : (T) -> R {
    private val cache = ConcurrentSkipListMap<T, R>()
    override fun invoke(x: T): R = cache.computeIfAbsent(x, f)
}

cFibonacci = Cached(::fibonacci)
```

... but the problem is, this only memoizes the outer-most call. If I call `cFibonacci` with a "big" number like `42`, it takes a long time and then puts the correct value in the memo; subsequent calls with the `42` will be fast, but `41` will be slow again. Compare this to `mFibonacci`, which runs fast the first time, and populates the memo with values from `0` up to `42`.

In Python, I can write a "decorator" which does this.

```
def memoized(f):
    def helper(t):
        if x in helper.memo:
          return helper.memo[t]
        else:
          r = f(t)
          helper.memo[t] = r
          return r
    helper.memo = {}
    return helper

@memoized
def fib(n):
  if n < 2:
    return n
  else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

This works just like `mFibonacci` above. I can also call it as `fib = memoized(fib)` if I imported `fib` from somewhere else and don't have access to the definition. Interestingly, `c_fib = memoized(fib)` works like `Cached`/`cFibonacci` above, hinting that maybe mutability of function reference is necessary.

The question is: **(how) can I wrap/"decorate" a recursive function in a way that affects the inner calls in Kotlin the way I can in Python?**

Comment: I think you can't because in the first code snippet the "fibonacci" call in "fibonacci" function is resolved during compilation or linkage to call this specific function. For Python the call is resolved on execution to call the function which is stored as "fib" at that time. It isn't the original "fib" function which it was before the decorator was applied.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a workaround in the absence of a solution. This pattern requires access to the definition of the function (i.e. it can't be an import):

```
object fibonacci: (Int) -> BigInteger {
    private val memo = ConcurrentSkipListMap<Int, BigInteger>()
    override fun invoke(n: Int): BigInteger = fibonacci(n)
    private fun fibonacci(n: Int): BigInteger = memo.computeIfAbsent(n) {
        if (n < 2)
            n.toBigInteger()
        else
            fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    }
}
```

There are few decisions here that may need justification:

1. I'm using a camelCase name instead of PascalCase. Despite the fact that `object` is a class, it's being called as a function and so I feel the naming convention of a function is better. With this, you can call the `fibonacci` function exactly as you normally would.
2. I've renamed `invoke` to `fibonacci`. Without this, the recursive calls use `invoke` which seems less readable to me. With this, you can read and write the `fibonacci` function (almost*) exactly as you normally would.

In general, the idea is to be the least intrusive as possible while still adding the desired functionality. I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it though!

*Something to note is that the function is defined using lambda syntax, so there is no `return`. If you have a single return at the end of the function, you just remove the `return` keyword. If you have multiple returns, you'll have to use the less-than-beautiful `return@computeIfAbsent` for the short-circuits.

Comment: I would make it a regular function with the private property and implementing function next to it. Then you don’t end up with the `object`-that’s-a-function weirdness.

Comment: @Tenfour04 If I understand the suggestion correctly, I don't believe that will persist the memo after running once. Maybe it was unclear in my question but I would like the memo to stay populated across multiple runs.

Comment: How does this even differ from what you did in the question itself? Your goal was to do this without touching the function but here you still have the `memo.computeIfAbsent(n)` inside the function

Comment: @IvoBeckers It's true that I had to touch the function to do it, that's why I said it was a workaround and not a solution. This is basically just an implementation of the `mFibonacci` idea, but where the memo is attached to the function implementation via the `object` wrapper. If there's a better answer, I'd love to hear it, but so far there hasn't been anything, and I figure this might be helpful to someone out there.

Comment: My suggestion wouldn’t behave differently. It will preserve the data.

Comment: @Tenfour04 In that case, would you mind adding it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

As requested, this is a variation of @AlexJones's workaround that doesn't wrap the function in an `object` with unconventional naming. I did not test this--it's based on the assumption that the other solution works. The following code would be at the top level of a .kt file.

```
private val memo = ConcurrentSkipListMap<Int, BigInteger>()

fun fibonacci(n: Int): BigInteger = fibonacciImpl(n)

private fun fibonacciImpl(n: Int): BigInteger = memo.computeIfAbsent(n) {
    if (n < 2)
        n.toBigInteger()
    else
        fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
}
```